# Need bump map example for libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to figure out how to use a bump map. I can add one to a model but nothing happens, probably need to turn on some config option. Please point me to a working example.

I only got this far:

```
matPlaceholder = new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color.RED), new TextureAttribute(TextureAttribute.Bump, texBump);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it, but the default shader doesn't do Bump Mapping yet.

There are plans of having a composite shader that does that and more. But as far as I know, it isn't ready. You need to write your own shader for that.

There is some good shaders [here](https://github.com/xoppa/libgdx/tree/2e83f93dfa56b7c4bd62297c1f2cadcaf9f91d80/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/g3d/shaders). Like Normal Mapping. You can give them a try.